# Android, use WebView with loadData

Tags: android, android-webview

im trying to use WebView like this:

```
    String html = " <html><body> 
    <table style\"background-color: #0a82a4; color: #ffffff;\"> 
       ... stuff ...
    </table>"
    </body>
    </head>";

    html.replace("#", "%23");
    html.replace("\\", "%27");
    html.replace("?", "%3f");
    html.replace("%", "%25");

    myWebview.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

It Works, but when add width=100% in style tag, webView cant load the data.

I used this reference: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

**loll, solved:**

```
html = html.replace("%", "%25");
html = html.replace("#", "%23");
html = html.replace("\\", "%27");
html = html.replace("?", "%3f");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I changed the order of replace calls:

```
html = html.replace("%", "%25");
html = html.replace("#", "%23");
html = html.replace("\\", "%27");
html = html.replace("?", "%3f");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the HelloWorld example in the devguide located [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)

Comment: this example only uses loadUrl method